# Offset in Update Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with name `MyTable` from which I want the data that has the same data in two columns i.e `email_id` and `user_id` and update the user_id columns to `Null` except one entry(duplicate entry are there). I have written this query, but it says

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "offset"
> Position: 380

Query:

```
update MyTable set user_id =null
where notification_id is null and pull_out = 'PULL' and user_id in (select user_id from (select email_id, user_id, count(*) 
from Mytable mytable 
where user_id is not null
group by email_id, user_id
having count(*)>1) as whatever)
offset 1
```

Note: Got to know ..offset is not available in update query.

Can anyone help to suggest something in this query?

**Sample Input and Expected Output**:

[image: enter image description]

Comment: Can you share sample data and expected output?

Comment: Added the sample Input and Output result.

Comment: So, in your sample input there are three rows belonging to Abc and one to Xyz. In the sample output there is only one row belonging to Abc, one belonging to Xyz and two rows where it is impossible to say who they belong to (because at least Abc and Xyz have the same email matching the rows' email). May I ask why you want to do this? It seems strange that you want to erase such information from the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit a variable that will check if a new user_id is encountered during the `UPDATE` operation. Your User_id field will be updated to:

- the same "*User_id*" value, if the "*User_id*" value was not seen before (is not contained in the variable)
- `NULL` if the "*User_id*" value was seen before (is currently found inside the variable).

The variable gets updated every time a new "*User_id*" value is found.

```
SET @new_user_id = '' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

UPDATE tab
SET User_id = IF(User_id = @new_user_id, 
                 NULL,
                 @new_user_id := User_id);
ORDER BY User_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wurqGJftTs6cDAyZYPuUJG/0).